# UPDATE returning * in PostgreSQL fails

Tags: postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
 UPDATE subscribers AS s SET status = 1 
 FROM (SELECT id FROM subscribers 
       WHERE client_id = *** AND status = 0 ORDER BY id LIMIT 5) AS t 
 WHERE t.id = s.id AND status = 0 RETURNING *
```

(explanation: SELECT all rows that have status=0 BUT update them to status=1 and only bring me FIVE as maximum).

**I HAVE 11 rows in subscribers table with status = 0**

The issue I'm having is: when I execute this query in my code (node.js, it doesn't matter what programming language, it's a query problem) in the FIRST TOW loops (first queries) it's returning 5 ROWS (that's good, as i have LIMIT 5 in the inner query).

But in the LAST QUERY I have **0 records...** and in my table there's a row with status = 0 WAITING THERE TO BE FETCHED

Somebody has a clue? I'm stuck with this

Comment: Why do you run that in a loop in the first place? Why not get rid of the derived table and do a straight: `update subscribers set ... where client_id in (...) and status = 0`

Comment: Thenks for your comment, because it need to be "fast", and i though that doing it like this.. i would avoid to select and then updating the table (i'm doing both operation at the same time), maybe it's not supported or something... i'm still investigating this issue right now.

Comment: Why do you think that running multiple statements that update only some rows is faster then **one** statement updating all rows? And why do you only want 5 of the updated rows returned and not all of them?

Comment: What is your eventual goal ?

Comment: There will be more than 1 million of records in that table... and i though that ONE operation would be better than TWO =) maybe i'm mistaking.

Comment: Yes, one is better then two but you wrote that you do the update in a loop which means you are doing more then one update.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Note the `LIMIT` clause, in the subquery, which AFAIR, isn't supported for direct `UPDATE`. But of course, OP could have mentioned this ;-)

Comment: @mzalazar You are talking about "first query", "last query", and "loop" without telling us the full story. Please update your question to sketch your actual algorithm in full and you might get proper answers. Currently, we are guessing (however educatedly), what's going on.

Comment: The query works correctly in the first two runs... but in the third run brings no row, that's strange for me... because one row stay with status=0 in the table.

Comment: @mzalazar And the `client_id` of that row does match the one from the subselect?

Comment: it matchs all rows :-|

Comment: Again: why do you run that statement three times instead of once with a where clause for those client_ids you want to change?

Comment: i'm testing... of course there will be much more rows.

Comment: i'm running it in a loop avoiding memory comsumption (in case of massive rows.. lets say 50.000)

Comment: now only 11 rows... but imagine 100.000 or more... would i do ONE QUERY returning all that data in memory? i don't think so, that's why i do it like that (in a loop)

Comment: But maybe i need to do it in two separated queries (first SELECT.. then UPDATE), i'm still thinking about it.

Comment: Why would you need to keep everything in memory? Why do you think you need to process **all** rows that you updated?

Comment: it's like "LOCKING" the row... it can't be processed more than once... that's why i'm changing the row at the same time.

Comment: it's like: "Give me the row... but change it's status at the same time... so nobody will process it after me".

Comment: @mzalazar [`SELECT FOR UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) plus a cursor?

Comment: dhke Yes, i think i will do that, thanks for the suggestion... my query is not right at all =) Thanks everybody for your help!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that my code was sending queries in parallel (almost at the same time), and it was creating a "race" condition, because the inner query of "subsequents" queries was receiving OLD data (before the outer UPDATE of the first query)... so this was a RACE CONDITION... i solved it after a while, thanks for your help, i'm learning a lot from this.